# Why does deleting columns in the QGIS attribute table take longer than in ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, performance, table, delete

In QGis, I recognised that deleting columns takes quite a while - is there a faster way than doing it in the attribute table (in editing mode?). I am speaking about a table with ~ 300 000 lines...

Because in ArcGis the same procedure I just one click and the column is immediately deleted...in QGIS I have to wait several minutes...(there is a dialogue window where you can see how many objects are loaded so far.....but why does it load anything at all?)

Comment: and if I delete 4 columns at once it takes 4 times longer....after every deletion  QGis "is loading objects"....

Comment: I think this is more a bug report (or feature request if you want). Or are you actually really interested in the answer?

Comment: Yes I am interested how I can avoid these long waiting times - realy annoying  - but Ed Rollason and ndawson already helped me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the 'Table Manager' plugin?  I think much the best way of editing attribute tables.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing this through the attribute table dialog? If so, I'd suggest removing the field from the layer properties -> fields panel instead.

Comment: Yes, I did. But your tip is also helping a lot.
What I found out is, if I just disable all columns in the attribute table and zoom on the outside of the layer on the map - I also have no waiting times.

Thanks!